# Ошибка линкинга в проекте qt4+boost: boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception

Tags: компоновщик, boost, qt

```
basic_text_oprimitive.hpp:89: undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception
```

линкую с библиотеками буста: `boost_serialization`, `boost_system` и `boost_thread`. Линуксовая версия проекта компилится/линкуется без ошибок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переставил версию boost на 53 (была новейшая на момент вопроса 54) и после пары  пинков (выражаемых в #define _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501, например)откомпилировалось/слинковалось успешно